# PL/pgSQL function + client-side lo_import

Tags: postgresql, psql, plpgsql

I have a problem with importing documents into PostgreSQL. I have a `plpgsql` function, which simplified could look like this:

```
create function add_file(flag integer, sth varchar) returns void as
begin
   if flag = 1 then 
      insert into tab_one values (my_file_oid, sth);
   else
      insert into tab_two values (my_file_oid, sth);
   end if;
end;
```

I'm using the `psql` command:

```
\lo_import('path/to/file');
```

Both the function and the `lo_import` command are in the same .sql file.

I cant change the `lo_import()` to an `INSERT` statement, becouse I need client-site `lo_import`. There is variable `LASTOID`, but it is not avaible in the `add_file` function, and it wouldnt get updated updating on every call `add_file()`.

So, how can I insert a large object into the database with, in our example, 'flag' and 'sth' by insert statement and everything in function with arguments?

The file to be loaded is on the client computer.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql` is the wrong tool for this kind of job because it basically can't get results into variables. It's good for user interface and static scripts, but for
interactive scripting where results from one operation are to be piped into another, it falls short. The best solution is to switch to a real scripting language such as Perl or Python that have good client-side APIs, including large-objects streaming.

When limited to bash, it's still possible to operate psql from the outside with [coproc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html) to get results out and back in, but it's much more complicated.

Comment: I wrote about the `coproc` approach [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8305578/398670), but like Daniel I'd really recommend using a language with native postgresql support - Python, Java, Perl, etc. Many of those languages' PostgreSQL client drivers support client-side import of large objects.